# Sending iOS push notifications from c#

Tags: c#, apple-push-notifications

I am having issue finding a working way to connect to the APNS and send push notifications from c#.

I have tried implementing PushSharp(https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp) but i get an error with "ConnectionError" status code, which i cannot resolve. It seems that it is no longer being worked on and afew users are getting the same error.

Can anyone guide me to an alternate library or a diffrent approach?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Azure mobile services.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/app-service/mobile/

With a .Net backend selection. I am assuming you are using Xamarin if you are writing iOS in C#? If so here is  a tutorial specific to Xamarin.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-push/

Comment: This is something i have considered and may have to reconsider. I am against this approach as it means there is another middleman between my server and the targeted device. Plus azure could end up costing me and is another element to maintain.

Comment: With Xamarin being owned by Microsoft now it would seem the most reliable, stable option. I used Pusharp in the past on Android only. Had a hard time implementing it for iOS.